# How to use Subversion to switch between branches of a Visual Studio project with minimal extra steps

Tags: visual-studio, svn

I am using visual studio for my development..
I made two feature branches of a trunk, branch P and branch E.  Branch E I added a new project in its own directory.  I must delete this directory BEFORE I switch to branch P otherwise it makes a mess.  This works fine if I remember.  But if someone else adds a new project that I miss or I forget a directory then I get a mess again.

I have *.sou, *.user bin and obj set in the global ignores.

Now if I forget to delete any directories not existing in branch P from branch E when I switch from E to P the mess begins.  The versioned files get deleted in the working copy, but the directory remains since subversion has no idea what to do with it.  Thats fine.  Then when I switch the working copy from P to E I get a conflict "local unversioned, incoming add upon switch".

What is the best way to handle this?

The resolved command says to use the resolve command.  The resolve command says the only option I have for tree conflicts is to use "accept working" which is wrong but the only choice I see.  So once I issue that my new library is marked for deletion which is not what I need.

So then I need to checkout the new library to a separate directory not under subversion control.  Commit the changes to branch E to resolve the conflict, this will also delete the new library.  Then I have to copy the files from the checkout I just completed to my working copy then add the new directory just to get where I was.  Not to mention what it must do the the history.

I must be doing something the hard way but I find nothing in the book to guide me, the subversion mailing list doesn't help either.  Has anyone found a better solution?

Comment: Why are switching between branches (branch E, P and trunk) so often? Pick a branch, and when you're done with it (and after your usual QA is completed) merge the changes across to other branches (usually, branch E/P to trunk, then from trunk to branch P/E). If that doesn't work, simply checkout all three branches and open up the ones you're working on in different instances of Visual Studio.

Comment: I wish I didn't have to switch back and forth so much.  But I can't always pick what I wish to work on, sometimes the business forces my hand.

Answer (score 0):

I finally received an answer from the subversion mailing list.  Actually I received two.

1) I can make different working directories for each branch.  That may work for some things, but I would have to duplicate the environment too.  Maybe I can redirect things to minimize the impact, but I am not looking for a time intensive solution.

2) I can use the --force option.  This cures it.  I'll find out if it causes any other problems but for now I can move right along.